# Questions about Eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transformation

I'm learning about Eigenspaces and have a few questions.

- Do eigenspaces, eigenvalues, and eigenvectors correspond to a tranformation or can a single vector space $V$ have an eigen-stuff?
- Is an eigenspace dependent on an eigenvalue or can multiple eigenvalues have the same eigenspace?

I thought I had a lot more questions. If I remember them I'll look it up before asking another question!

Thank you guys.

Comment: I dont understand question 2. About 1 yes, the definition of eigenvalue depens on a linear aplication.

Comment: Question 1: Only *linear transformations* have eigenstuff.  Question 2: Go back and look up the definition of [eigenspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenspace_and_spectrum) (and maybe [invariant subspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace) for good measure).

Comment: sorry, there were a lot of bad typos on the question, haha. I went back and edited it!

Answer (score 0):

The eigendata refers to invariants of transformations. 
 Different eigenvalues correspond to different eigenvectors/spaces, but not necessarily vice versa.